# React Native: Create Time List using FlatList and DatePicker

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-flatlist

**Objective:** To show a list of Time when the user selects Time from the DatePicker.

**Problem:** It only shows a *single Time* instead of list of times.

I can select time from the Datepicker. And when I clicked *ok*, the Selected time is shown on the flatlist. However upon selecting a *new* time, the *old* time gets replaced. This results in showing only 1 time on the list.

I have added screenshot of the app below.

Hence, any kind of help regarding solving this problem will be appreciated.

**Code snippet below:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import moment from 'moment';

export default class FrCreateScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //Time
            appointmentTime: new Date(moment()),
            modeAppointmentTime: 'time',
            showAppointmentTime: false,
            textAppointmentTime: moment().format('h:mm a').toString(),

            //new timeSlots
            timeSlots: [],
        }
    }

    //[ timePicker start]
    setAppointmentTime = (event, appointmentTime, textAppointmentTime, timeSlots) => {
        appointmentTime = appointmentTime || this.state.appointmentTime;
        textAppointmentTime = textAppointmentTime || moment(appointmentTime).format('h:mm a').toString();
        this.setState({
            showAppointmentTime: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false,
            appointmentTime,
            textAppointmentTime,

            //newly added
            timeSlots: [{ time: textAppointmentTime }],
        });
    }

    showTime = (modeAppointmentTime, textAppointmentTime, timeSlots) => {
        textAppointmentTime = moment(this.state.appointmentTime).format('h:mm a').toString();
        this.setState({
            showAppointmentTime: true,
            modeAppointmentTime,
            textAppointmentTime,

            //newly added
            timeSlots: [{ time: textAppointmentTime }],
        })
    }

    timePicker = () => {
        this.showTime('time');
    }
    //[ timePicker end ]

    getAppointmentTimePage() {
        //const { timeSlots, selectedValue } = this.state;
        const {
            appointmentTime,
            showAppointmentTime,
            modeAppointmentTime,
            textAppointmentTime
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={[styles.title, { marginTop: 20 }]}>Select Appointment Time:</Text>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.timePicker}>
                        <Text style={styles.textDate}>
                            {textAppointmentTime}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>}
                    {showAppointmentTime && <DatePicker
                        value={appointmentTime}
                        mode={modeAppointmentTime}
                        onChange={this.setAppointmentTime}
                        minimumDate={new Date(moment())}
                    />}
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.addText}>Add Appointment</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.getAppointmentTimePage()}
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.timeSlots}
                            keyExtractor={(times) => times.time}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                return (
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={styles.textTime}>{item.time}</Text>
                                        <TouchableOpacity>
                                            <Feather name="trash" style={styles.icon} />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    };
};
```

[image]

Comment: I think on click of `AddAppointment` you want to push the time slot to the array. So instead of doing `timeSlots: [{ time: textAppointmentTime }]` , you might want to do `timeSlots: this.state.timeSlots.push({ time: textAppointmentTime })`. Also I cannot see the code for `Add Appointment` button in the attached snippet.

Comment: I have the added the `Add Appointment` button. Initially it was there just for show and didn't contain any function. Regarding the line of code that you provided, I am getting this warning: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _this.state.timeSlots.push is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only change you have to do is append item in array instead of update array object.

```
timeSlots: [...this.state.timeSlots,{ time: textAppointmentTime }],
```

Mistake was that you were treating array as object.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem as the app lists all the selected time properly. I am a bit weak regarding objects and array and I am still learning at the moment. Once again, Thank you.